# iPhone self-assigning IP address 169.xxx.xxx when connecting to my slave router

Tags: wireless-networking, iphone, dhcp, ip-address

My aim is to have a network configured where all devices can see and communicate with each other, all devices should have access to the internet as standard.

The reason why I have decided on a cascading network setup with a "Master" and "Slave" is because my WiFi didn't reach to all places in the house and our phones / ipads were not connected to the network in the main rooms that we use.

My Network Configuration
(Master) ADSL Modem Router < [PLUG] -- Connected to Belkin Powerline HD (200Mbps) -- [PLUG] > (Slave) Old router WiFi Enabled

1. Slave is connected  to the powerline HD plug via a LAN port with the DHCP server settings turned off and the DHCP server pointing to the Master routers IP Address, which has its DHCP server settings switched on.

   - This config works with all my devices laptops, printers, DLNA servers etc.
   - However none of my apple devices work with it, the IP address of my iPhone 5 is being self assigned 169.xxx.xxx.xxx ("x" being a number from1 - to - 254)

Now I want to know is there any reason why my apple iPhone or iPad cannot work within this setup, I can't see why not, my master should assign the iPhone an IP address within the defined range however this doesn't seem to be the case.

This issue got me thinking so I though I would play around with the setup to see if I could get it working. My hunch was that it might be something to do with the powerline so I tried connecting the "Slave" directly to the "Master" and it worked so kind of proved my first theory.

I then tried changing the Slave settings, so that slave would become the DHCP server for its own sub-net, I achieved this by:

2. Slave is connected to the powerline HD plug via internet (WAN) port on the router and turning the DHCP server setting on in the router

   - This config works with my iphones but now means any other devices that I connect to this WiFi cannot use any of my network resources unless I move them on to this wireless network - Which I can't as they are at the other side of the house where this signal does not reach
   - cannot see printers or any shared resources.

Is there any reason why my apple products cannot obtain an IP Address over the PowerLine HD plug or is there an alternative that could be suggested that would allow this to work, I can't run a cable either as its just impractical. If powerlines don't work I would just like to know why? my s4 and s3 both work fine on the first config.

Sorry if this sounds high level just the best way I could word it if any one needs more info I would be more than happy to provide specifics upon request - DESPERATLY want a solution to this.

Thanks in advance

Nik

Comment: Easiest solution is to set manual static ip for the iphone.

Comment: Yes I could do that, but then what do I do for visitors? most of my friends use the wifi in the house, surely there is a setting somewhere that would allow me to do all of this?

Comment: You can try to change the Slave to have its own DHCP, but don't use different subnet, but simply re-use the same subnet. But if say your Master gives DHCP from 192.168.1.10-100, let the slave do DHCP on 192.168.1.150-200 and see if that would work out for you.

Comment: this is not going to be helpful at all but while I was waiting for your responses, to get internet working on our phones again, I set the slave router to be its own DHCP and connect via the master (as ISP) giving it a diff sub-net 192.168.0.1 the master is on 192.168.1.1, I also connected the other end of the powerline into the WAN port of the slave. It didn't work immediately but I also installed UBUNTU on some of my machines (don't know if its relevant or not) connected like a day later and all of a sudden in works on all OS's and even our phones.